# Android Bluetooth Low Energy Glucose profile not able to read measurements

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am trying to read Glucose data from GL50Evo Ble device which has Bluetooth Glucose profile implemented I am not successful with it.

1. I have enabled NOTIFICATION on GLUCOSE MEASUREMENT CHARACTERISTICS
2. I have enabled NOTIFICATION on GLUCOSE MEASUREMENT CONTEXT CHARACTERISTICS
3. I have enabled INDICATION on GLUCOSE RECORD ACCESS CONTROL CHARACTERISTICS

Here is my code:

```
if(descriptor.getCharacteristic().getUuid().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(SupportedServices.CHARACTERISTIC_GLUCOSE_RECORD_ACCESS_CONTROL_UUID)) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2];
    // Op Code: 0x01 report stored records
    buffer[0] = 0x01;
    // Operator: 0x01 All records, 0x06 last one
    buffer[1] = 0x01;
    descriptor.getCharacteristic().setValue(buffer);
    descriptor.getCharacteristic().setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
    gatt.writeCharacteristic(descriptor.getCharacteristic());
}
```

`onCharacteristicsChanged()` is not getting called.

Please guys help me in this issue.

Comment: Did you try to read the characteristic first? It will confirm if the device has any value to that characteristic.

Comment: @AAnkit when I try to read the characteristic it returns false.

Comment: I am also getting the same problem. I have run my program for heart rate measurement and thermometer, its working fine. But for glucose, it never comes to onCharactersticsChanged() calls. Please help me if you have found any solution for this.

Comment: Did you guys find any solution? I am also facing the same issue.